# How do I retrieve a custom attribute in watir?

Tags: ruby, watir, win32ole

I'm trying to retrieve the "onclick" attribute value from the below link:

```
<a onclick="test" href="myurl">aaa</a>
```

Using `link.href` works fine (So I know `link` is the correct object) however when using `link.attribute_value("onclick")` what I get is a win32 object (puts shows `#<WIN32OLE:0x2cbdf10>` instead of the `"test"` string).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't get a neater solution, and it's a one off(If you can make sure the development process keeps this kind of testing in mind next time).Try:

```
onclick_value=browser.html[ %r{<a onclick="(.*?)" href="myurl">}mi, 1 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me (Windows 2003, ruby 1.8.7, watir 1.6.5):

```
browser.link(:href => /myurl/).attribute_value("onclick")
# => "test"
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested on Mac with watir-webdriver gem driving Firefox:

```
browser.link(:href => "myurl").html.split('"')[3]
# => "myurl"
```

Tested on Windows with watir gem driving IE:

```
browser.link(:href => /myurl/).html.split('"')[1]
# => "myurl"
```