# How to click a variable link?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, watir, watir-webdriver

Reference to Željko Filipin's answer on 
[How do I retrieve a custom attribute in watir?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710550/how-do-i-retrieve-a-custom-attribute-in-watir)

I have a number of links such as:

```html
<a href="//stackoverflow.com"
  title="professional and enthusiast programmers">Stack Overflow</a>
<a href="//programmers.stackexchange.com" 
  title="professional programmers interested in conceptual questions about software development">Programmers</a>
```

I have stored the links in an array; I need to click on the individual link.

```ruby
browser.link(:href => /stackoverflow/).click
```

Instead of "stackoverflow", I want to run through my array (i.e. replace with array variable):

```ruby
browser.link(:href => /array[i]/).click
```

Can anyone enlighten me how I can achieve this?

Comment: It would help to share what the contents of `array` are. For example is it an array of strings that you want insert into a regular expression or are they already regular expressions?

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you want?

```
  array.each { |link|
      browser.link(:href, 'link').click
    }
```

Comment: It looks like he wants the forward slashes, too (assuming they are required). So perhaps `(:href, "/#{link}/")` instead of just `(:href, 'link')`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a contrived example that will cycle through a list of `href` attributes and interpolate each into a loop that will click each link:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'

b = Watir::Browser.new
b.goto('http://www.iana.org/domains/reserved')
arr = %W(/domains /numbers /protocols)           # an array of strings
arr.each { |el| b.link(href: "#{el}").click}
```

The trick here is the interpolation syntax: `#{}`.  When placed within a double-quoted string, the code within `#{}` is evaluated and inserted into the string.  For instance:

```
# interpolate a string
str_to_insert = "world"
puts "hello #{str_to_insert}"
#=> hello world

# evaluate code before interpolation
puts "one plus two equals #{1 + 2}"
#=> one plus two equals 3
```